# getting tooltip text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tooltip

I am trying to scrape some dynamic content appear on mouse hover. I have tried ActionChains from the Selenium for the mouse movement and hover actions but unable to get the required text. The problem is that I am unable to get the specific position of the tooltip in the DOM. I tried to get it by using debugger paused option but the element not visible in the DOM. here is the link to the web page. https://www.capterra.com/p/174185/Weave-Accreditation/reviews/. I am also attaching a screenshot in which red rectangle highlight the content i want to scrape.[image]

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In debugger paused mode , we are able to search corresponding div for this tool tip.
**Trick :** Once you are in paused debugger mode, search tool tip string in HTML DOM. See below:[image]

Based on above DOM, i have used below code to print tool tip Text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.capterra.com/p/174185/Weave-Accreditation/reviews/")
driver.maximize_window()
toolTip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(text(),'Reviewer Source')]/div[contains(@class,'IconWrapper')][1]")))
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(toolTip)
txt = hov.perform()
tooltipText = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tippy-content']"))).text
print(tooltipText)
```

Comment: Alright, I get your point. This is working perfectly for me. Thank you.

Comment: one more thing, I am trying to iterate over the web page and get the exact same text from all the div. can you please update the script for this. Thank You

Comment: i have tried to update the above script as follow. toolTip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(text(),'Reviewer Source')][2]/div[contains(@class,'IconWrapper')][1]"))), but its keep on pushing timeout exception

Comment: @AffifaTaskeen The reason you are getting Timeout is because xPath used by you is not identifying any element. Its always a good practice to check your xpath by copying it in Element Inspect (F12)> Element tab > Search (Ctrf+F) > Your xPath. If its correct it will show how many element are identified by it.

Comment: Coming back to your question, can you be more specific which all divs text you want to print? As in your page there are total 1384 divs  in your page:). Anyway try something with findelements method and iterate through all divs. One more request please start separate question thread if your original issue asked is resolved. Cheers !!!