# How do I scrape the text that appears when I hover over the element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

On the web page (https://www.oddsmath.com/football/italy/serie-a-1315/2023-02-26/ac-milan-vs-atalanta-4052172/), the odds are displayed when I hover over them with the mouse, but I'm not able to get these values

```
<div class="history-row history normal-odds"><span class="time">Feb 26, 20:47</span><b class="odd-value">2.26</b><span class="arrow-up arrH">▲</span>(<span class="sign sgnp">+0.01</span>)</div>
```

in this case I want to get "2.26"

```
wbe.get('https://www.oddsmath.com/football/italy/serie-a-1315/2023-02-26/ac-milan-vs-atalanta-4052172/#DC')
sleep(2)
elements=WebDriverWait(wbe,2).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="table-odds-cat-0"]/tbody/tr[19]/td[3]/div[2]')))
for el in elements:
    ActionChains(wbe).move_to_element(el).perform()
    mouseover=WebDriverWait(wbe,2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="history-row history normal-odds"]'))).text
    print(mouseover)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting tooltip text using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430314/getting-tooltip-text-using-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0):

To get a hidden text you have to use `.get_attribute('innerText')`. For example, this code prints all the hidden values in the table column with label `1`.

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#table-odds-cat-0 > tbody > tr')
for idx,row in enumerate(rows):
    print('\nrow',idx+1)
    tooltip = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td[class*=odds-1] > .tooltip .odd-value')
    for t in tooltip:
        print(t.get_attribute('innerText'), end=' ')
```

Output

```
row 1
2.15 2.16 2.17 2.26 2.32 2.35 2.29 2.30 2.30 2.24 2.24 2.30 2.27 2.27 2.24 2.23 2.23 2.25 2.24 2.21 2.28 
row 2
2.30 2.25 2.25 2.30 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.20 2.25 2.25 2.20 
row 3
2.26 2.28 2.29 2.29 2.28 2.26 2.23 2.23 2.26 2.28 2.26 2.25 2.23 2.26 2.23 2.20 2.22 2.22 2.21 2.22 2.16 
row 4
2.12 2.14 2.12 2.07 2.04 2.12 2.12 2.07 2.14 2.12 2.14 2.10 2.14 2.14 2.20 2.23 2.17 2.18 2.12 2.18 2.15 
row 5
2.24 2.23 2.24 2.23 2.22 2.23 2.24 2.25 2.26 2.25 2.27 2.23 2.23 2.22 2.23 2.22 2.20 2.18 2.17 2.18 2.19 
row 6
2.28 2.34 2.24 2.28 2.20 2.18 2.19 2.24 2.25 2.26 2.26 2.28 2.25 2.24 2.26 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.19 2.20 2.27 
row 7
2.25 2.30 2.25 2.20 2.20 2.25 2.25 2.20 2.15 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.25 2.25 2.20 2.15 2.20 2.15 2.20 2.15 2.20 
row 8
2.17 2.22 2.19 2.19 2.17 2.15 2.15 2.17 2.14 2.15 2.10 2.10 2.13 2.15 2.14 2.15 2.26 2.29 2.29 2.34 2.34 
row 9
2.20 
row 10
2.29 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.22 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.20 2.17 2.20 2.17 2.30 
row 11
2.31 2.31 2.28 2.26 2.26 2.31 2.31 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.26 2.25 2.26 2.28 2.28 2.28 2.29 2.23 
row 12
2.15 2.16 2.17 2.26 2.32 2.35 2.29 2.30 2.30 2.24 2.24 2.30 2.27 2.27 2.24 2.23 2.23 2.25 2.24 2.21 2.28 
row 13
1.09 1.09 1.14 1.15 1.14 1.15 1.20 1.22 1.25 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 1.30 2.30 
row 14
2.29 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.22 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.20 2.17 2.20 2.17 2.30 
row 15
2.38 2.38 2.36 2.35 2.38 2.32 2.33 2.33 2.27 2.27 2.33 2.30 2.30 2.27 2.26 2.26 2.28 2.27 2.24 2.26 2.30 
row 16
2.15 2.16 2.17 2.26 2.32 2.35 2.29 2.30 2.30 2.24 2.24 2.30 2.27 2.27 2.24 2.23 2.23 2.25 2.24 2.21 2.28 
row 17
2.30 2.25 2.25 2.30 
row 18
2.29 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.22 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.29 2.20 2.17 2.20 2.17 2.30 
row 19
2.26 2.25 2.26 2.26 2.26 2.23 2.23 2.28 2.25 2.26 2.24 2.24 2.26 2.20 2.20 2.23 2.28 2.26 2.24 2.24 2.18 
row 20
2.20 2.28 2.29 2.24 2.28 2.20 2.18 2.19 2.24 2.25 2.26 2.26 2.28 2.27 2.29 2.23 2.23 2.22 2.25 2.23 2.30 
row 21
2.20 2.25 2.20 2.15 2.10 2.05 2.10 2.15 2.20 2.15 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.05 2.05 2.10 
row 22
2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.30 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.15 2.20 2.20 2.30 
row 23
2.20 2.14 2.16 2.14 2.08 2.06 2.12 2.15 2.15 2.16 2.15 2.08 2.14 2.15 2.14 2.15 2.14 2.15 2.16 2.20 2.14 
row 24
2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.20 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.30 2.33 2.30
```